# Apps Script Code wont delete a boolean Value - Apps Script / GoogleSheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code below that works fine for deleting rows containing certain text.

```
function DeleteTRUE(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('HOLDING'), true);
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[4] == "TRUE") {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
}
```

However when I put a TRUE to try to delete a row (that has a checkbox) and someone checks it,
it doesnt work. It is being triggered from an onEdit currently with the word "MOVE" which is working as it should. would prefer if it was a checkbox that they checked and it deleted the row.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I create default checkboxes equal `true` works for me fine

```
function deleteTRUE() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('HOLDING'), true);
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[4] == true) {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};
```

If you need check for `"TRUE"` you have override validation values.

[image]

It's very important you need to type `'TRUE` `'FALSE` for string interpretation.

Comment: Hi Contributorpw - as simple as that.As soon as I tried lower case true - worked perfectly. thanks very much